# Python dictionary key error only in one specific case

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a class that stores a list of lists in a matrix style, and it can just be indexed like [x,y].

Right now I have these set:

```
test_dict = {1:"cow",2:"horse"}

randommap = mapArray(None, (20,20))
```

random map is just filled with lists of 1s. So any index will return a 1. But here is where I get lost, maybe because of a misunderstanding about how dictionaries work:

```
test_dict[1]
```

That obviously gives back "cow"
and

```
randommap[1,1] #or any two x,y values up to 20 for that matter
```

gives me a value of 1.

But how come this gives me a key error:

```
test_dict[randommap[1,1]]
```

In isolation, indexing randommap there gives me a value of 1, so shouldn't that 1 be supplied as an index for test_dict, thus returning me "cow"?

Update:
These are the two methods I presume are causing the issue. It appears that they are returning strings instead of integers, but I don't know If I quite understand the difference between the two.

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.mapdata)

def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.mapdata)
```

Here is the overloaded `__getitem__` method:

```
def __getitem__(self, (x,y)):
    #Just reverses it so it works intuitively and the array is 
    # indexed simply like map[x,y] instead of map[y][x]
    return mapArray(self.mapdata[y][x])
```

Sorry the formatting seems to have been messed up a bit.

Comment: What is the output of `type(randommap[1, 1])`?

Comment: perhaps randommap returns a string `'1'`?

Comment: It would be useful if you posted the full traceback of your `KeyError`.

Comment: But wouldn't the value returned in this instance be determined by `__getitem__`?

Comment: Ah good point - I thought the OP had posted that overload too. @Ryan: could you post if you overloaded that too?

Comment: @mutzmatron Sure, I just added that overloaded method as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the updated question, it seems that `__getitem__` returns a new mapArray.

I think your overloaded `__getitem__` should be something like

```
def __getitem__(self, (x,y)):
    return self.mapdata[y][x]
```

instead, (assuming that the [y][x] order is intentional).

Comment: Ah, that seemed to fix it. Not quite sure why I had that there in the first place, but thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between `1` (and integer), `"1"` (a string), and any custom class whose `__repr__()` method returns the string `"1"` when called. They will all be printed as `1` in the console, but are not equivalent for dict look-ups.

You need to check that `type(randommap[1, 1])` is indeed an `int`.

Update: Your `__getitem__` method doesn't return integers, it returns a new instance of your `mapArray` class. Did you mean to return just the values themselves? E.g.:

```
def __getitem__(self, (x,y)):
    #Just reverses it so it works intuitively and the array is 
    # indexed simply like map[x,y] instead of map[y][x]
    return self.mapdata[y][x]
```

Comment: He can cast the return to make sure its an int with `test_dict[int(randommap[1, 1])]`, but that could raise a ValueError if the value returned by randommap can't be cast to an integer.

Comment: @JoeDay: Since we are all guessing here let's stick to troubleshooting information. :-)

Comment: type(randommap[1,1]) gives me `<class '__main__.mapArray'>`. I am new to operator overloading, so this class probably has some issues.

Comment: @Ryan: either update the question (or better yet), create a new one. Comments are not suited for troubleshooting.